# Android Studio. How to access another button in a OnClick method?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

So I want to connect a OnClick method to a button A, but what i want its when i click that button A, other buttons(B, C, D, F) will become visible. But when i run the code it crashu, Anybody can help me?

```
     public void OnClick(View v) 
{
    b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    c.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    d.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    f.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

I add this method to my button A in the activity_main.xml.

Comment: please post yout error log and you class complete code

Comment: post the full class.

Comment: I already post the full class, hope you can help me

Comment: what is your error in log?

Comment: post also your activity_main.xml please

Comment: i posted the activity_main.xml, the error appear when i cleck the button, the app stop working

Comment: @MárioCaldas, check my answer, I just updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this complete code:

```
ImageButton imB1, op1, op2, op3, op4, op5, op6, op7, op8;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    imB1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgB1);
    op1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.esc1);
    op2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.esc2);
    op3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.esc3);
    op4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.esc4);
    op5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.esc5);
    op6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.esc6);
    op7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.esc7);
    op8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.esc8);


}

public void Clicked(View v) {
    op1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

And change this in your xml:

```
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background"
android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:id="@+id/imgB1"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
android:onClick="Clicked" /> //here changes are made
```

Comment: you have keeped uppercase method name

Answer (score 0):

Your first button should be as follows:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/checkbox_off_background"
    android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgB1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="onClick" />
```

According to the last line your method in your MainActivity should be as follows (with o of OnClick lower case)

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    op1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op6.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op7.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    op8.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Without the error log we can't help you more precisely than that

Comment: I change to lower case but still crash, i post the error log